# How to let particular advertiser purchase a pre roll ad for our videos?

Tags: youtube, video, ads

We have a local company that wants to run a video pre roll campaign on all of the videos on our channel.

How do we set this up?

Do they have to create an AdSense account first or something? Can we just upload their video for them?

Can we upload their video to our AdSense account and then just target our videos?

Answer (score 1):

Advertisers can [reserve ads on certain channels by going through the sales team](https://support.google.com/google-ads/answer/6030919?hl=en), however, this only applies if the advertiser wants to spend a lot of money. Like, "L'Oreal wanting all ads on beauty channels for a week"-kind of money.

Advertisers can also just do [placement targeting](https://support.google.com/google-ads/answer/7131506?hl=en) onto a single channel, however, there's no guarantee that their ad will be played in front of the video - other advertisers can out-bid them, even if those other advertisers don't care about your channel in particular.

Because of this, what usually happens is that instead of doing pre-rolls, advertisers interested in closer relationships with creators are doing letting creators do endorsements instead. These involve the creator making the endorsement themselves (usually by following a script the advertiser gave them) near the end of the video, and a very quick "this video was sponsored by " near the beginning of the video.

Note that there are rules on what you can and cannot do for these endorsements: https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/154235?hl=en
Most importantly, you **mustn't burn pre-rolls into your video**.